Ascii-Table Logging Commands/Events || Discord.js
const table = new AsciiTable('Commands')
                table
                    .setHeading('Command', 'Loaded')
                    .addRow(file, '✔')
                    console.log(table.toString())

Here's is my code, I thought making it like this would allow it to make multiple rows with the data. It only logs one command in the table than creates another table with another command. I would like to know how to add all the data in one table without creating multiple rows.
Here is my full code:
module.exports = (client) => {
    for (const type of readdirSync('./src/commands/')) {
        for (const dir of readdirSync('./src/commands/' + type)) {
            for (const file of readdirSync('./src/commands/' + type + '/' + dir).filter((f) => f.endsWith('.js'))) {
                const module = require('../commands/' + type + '/' + dir + '/' + file);

                if (!module) continue;

                if (type === 'prefix') {
                    if (!module.structure?.name || !module.run) {
                        log('Unable to load the command ' + file +' due to missing \'structure#name\' or/and \'run\' properties.', 'warn');
        
                        continue;
                    };

                    client.collection.prefixcommands.set(module.structure.name, module);

                    if (module.structure.aliases && Array.isArray(module.structure.aliases)) {
                        module.structure.aliases.forEach((alias) => {
                            client.collection.aliases.set(alias, module.structure.name);
                        });
                    };
                } else {
                    if (!module.structure?.name || !module.run) {
                        log('Unable to load the command ' + file +' due to missing \'structure#name\' or/and \'run\' properties.', 'warn');
        
                        continue;
                    };

                    client.collection.interactioncommands.set(module.structure.name, module);
                    client.applicationcommandsArray.push(module.structure);
                };
                const table = new AsciiTable('Commands')
                table
                    .setHeading('Command', 'Loaded')
                    .addRow(file, '✔')
                    console.log(table.toString())
            };
        };
    };
};

